# API 34.0 introduces INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY on portal user self-updating contact?

Tags: dmlexception, userrecordaccess, summer-15, high-volume-portal

I have the following test that asserts that a portal user is able to update it's own contact first name.

```
@IsTest
public class MyTestClass {

    @IsTest
    static void portalUserSelfUpdateContact() {

        Account ac = new Account(Name = 'the account');
        insert ac;

        Contact ct = new Contact(LastName = 'contact_lastname', AccountId = ac.Id);
        insert ct;

        Profile pf = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE UserType = 'CspLitePortal' LIMIT 1];

        User usr = new User(
            Alias                 = 'usralias',
            Email                 = 'theuser@email.com',
            Emailencodingkey      = 'UTF-8',
            Lastname              = 'user_lastname',
            Languagelocalekey     = 'en_US',
            Localesidkey          = 'en_US',
            Profileid             =  pf.Id,
            Timezonesidkey        = 'America/Los_Angeles',
            Username              =  Math.random() + 'test@testuser.com',
            ContactId             =  ct.Id,
            CompanyName           = 'the company',
            Salesforce_Edition__c = 'DE',
            IsPortalSelfRegistered = true
        );

        System.runAs(usr) {
            ct.FirstName = 'contact_firstname';
            update ct;
        }
    }
}
```

When I compile the class using API 33.0, the test passes. But when I try with API 34.0, the update fails with this message.

> System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id
>   005Q000000NtSmRIAV; first error:
>   INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient access
>   rights on cross-reference id: []

What has changed in API 34.0 that causes this issue. What other changes should I make in my code for this test to pass?

**Notes**
Similar question [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/86264), but API version is not mentioned.
Here's the same question in [developer.salesforce.com forums](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F0000000BUybIAG).

Comment: Did you solve this issue please share your solution?

Comment: @ThysMichels I wasn't able to solve, past keeping the class in API 33.0.
I also confirmed that the problem persists in API 37.0 (as of this date).

Comment: What are your org-wide defaults for Account and Contact?

Comment: Good question! I just ran the test again in API 40 and it's still failing. Both of those sharing rules are Public Read Only (just freshly changed from Private).

Comment: Summer '15 added the [`System.Site.createExternalUser()`](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer15/release-notes/rn_apex_new_classes_methods.htm) method to "creates a new community or portal user and associates them with the specified account in a community or portal". Probably unrelated as your exception is around updating the FirstName rather than creating the user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the behavior in v34 is fixing bad behavior in v33. Take a look at [this link](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customer_portal_manage_users.htm&type=0) (emphasis mine) "All users in a customer portal role (Executive, Manager, and User roles) have *read* access to all portal-enabled contacts under their portal account even when the contact sharing model is private." I wasn't able to find any source that says this is different for the user's contact - meaning that the user has read-only access to their own contact as well. This is backed up by [this discussion](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=087300000006tto). This means that you will need to grant access to the contact record in some way, shape or form.

Here are two ways to grant access off the top of my head:

1. **Change the Org-Wide Sharing Defaults.** Right now in your org you have mentioned that they are public read-only. Change them to public read-write.
2. **Use a utility class that specifies `without sharing`.** This allows the user to access the records as long as the have edit access on the object. Here is one I made that worked with your sample code:

   ```
   public without sharing MyTestClass2 {
     public static void updateContact(Contact ctc) {
       ctc.FirstName = 'contact_firstname';
       update ctc;
     }
   }
   ```

I then replaced everything in `runAs` with a call to this method:

```
    System.runAs(usr) {
        MyTestClass2.updateContact(ct);
    }
```

I don't have an explanation for the behavior before v34; perhaps there was a bug in the way that Salesforce handled sharing of a record when used in `runas`? I compared the v33 and v34 pages for Apex Sharing, `System.runAs()`, `with sharing` vs `without sharing`, and anything else I could think might have an impact, but did not see any significant changes. Obviously, if neither of these solutions fix your problem then there is something else causing issues. However, I believe Salesforce documentation and the links provided indicate v34 is behaving in the expected manner.

Comment: Thanks Cameron. I just tested and the problem persists in version 39.0. Your solution of using a helper without sharing class does work around the problem and should solve the issue for anyone experiencing this problem. Thanks again!